# Prob. 4, Sec. 21 in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: How to decide which cases to consider?

Tags: general-topology

We need to show that the ordered square satisfies the first countability axiom.

I'm not able to decide as to which separate cases to consider.

By definition the ordered square is the product $I \times I$, where $I \colon= [0,1]$, in the dictionary order topology.

And, a topological space $X$ is said to satisfy the first countability axiom if each $x \in X$ has a countable basis, that is, if, for each $x \in X$, we have a countable collection $\{ U_{xn} \ \colon \ n \in \mathbb{N} \ \}$ of open sets containing $x$ such that, for every open set $U$ in $X$ containing $x$, there is some natural number $n$ such that $U_{xn} \subset U$.

Let $x \times y \in I \times I$. Then $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $0 \leq y \leq 1$.

Now which cases do we have to consider?

Comment: There are two cases: the easy case is when $0<y<1$ and the other case is when $y\in \{0,1 \}$.

Comment: @Crostul, are these two cases exhaustive?

Comment: Don't you think that $0<y<1$ or $y=0,1$? There are no other cases, obviously.

Comment: You may find it a little easier to consider the cases $y=0$ and $y=1$ separately: they involve the same basic idea, but the details are just a little different.

Comment: See https://dbfin.com/topology/munkres/chapter-2/section-21-the-metric-topology-(continued)/problem-4-solution/